# How to add key-value pairs to hash in a loop

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to add key-value pairs to a hash in a loop. My hash looks like this

```
[ {'filename' => fileName1, 'filelocation'=> fileLocation1}, {'filename' => fileName2, 'filelocation'=> fileLocation2} ]
```

I am using the following code to do it. It does not add all values, but the very last key-value pair.

```
fileDetails= {}
doc = REXML::Document.new args[0]
doc.elements.each("node/congfigurations/config") {
 |config| 
    fileName= config.elements["@fileName"].value
    fileLocation= config.elements["@location"].value
    fileDetails={'filename' => fileName, 'filelocation'=> fileLocation}
}
```

How can I collect all values?

Comment: make `fileDetails= []` instead of `fileDetails= {}`. Use the method `#<<` .. like this `fileDetails << {'filename' => fileName, 'filelocation'=> fileLocation}`

Comment: What you claim is a hash is not a hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your expected output is not a Hash, its an array. So declare it like this

```
fileDetails = []
```

And inside the loop, make this change

```
fileDetails << {'filename' => fileName, 'filelocation'=> fileLocation}
# push the Hash into the array
```

**EDIT**

"*It does not add all values, but the very last key-value pair*"

This is because, you are using the assignment operator. So every time in the loop, the variable gets reassigned, and in the end you will have the last assigned value.

Comment: Just explain *It does not add all values, but the very last key-value pair.* .. I know it is very simple to explain. just do it.. to complete your answer. :-)